# Chrome slow, accessing Local Storage\chrome-extension_randomname

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Whenever my Google Chrome comes to a screeching halt pause, I notice in Resource Monitor that there's a heck of a lot of file I/O on a file named c:\Users\username\Appdata\local\google\chrome\user data\Default\Local Storage\chrome-extension_randomgeneratedname

Opening this file in NotePad++ shows that it's a SQLite file, but I can't grok any more from the contents.

Is there a way to tell which Chrome extension owns this file without going through the exhaustive process of individual elimination?

Comment: Have you already tried a sqlite viewer? Have you already grepped your extensions' source code for `localStorage`?

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally stumbled on the answer:

If you open up Tools->Extensions, it actually lists the ID of each installed extension right under the extension name.  That ID is appended to the filename.